# Wordpress redirecting

Tags: wordpress

im gonna change wordpress theme on one of my website and this will change all the links.

What would be the best/fastest way to redirect around 100 pages from:
**domain.com/portfolio/123** to **domain.com/123** (name without portfolio).

Thanks,
Julija

Comment: There is a script that does this for all the DB tables. http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a rule in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```